# Magento 2 - Use Bootstrap 4 (Uncaught Error: Script error for: bootstrap)

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, theme, custom-theme, bootstrap4

I try to install bootstrap 4.

> **Note**: `THEME_LOCATION` => *app\design\frontend\company\base*

---

First I downloaded the **Compiled CSS and JS** from [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/).

I moved the file *bootstrap.min.css* to **THEME_LOCATION\web\css\bootstrap.min.css**

and *bootstrap.bundle.min.js* to **\web\js\bootstrap.bundle.min.js**

Then I added the requirement to

> THEME_LOCATION\Magento_Theme\requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'bootstrap':'Magento_Theme/js/bootstrap.bundle.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Then in **default_head_blocks.xml** I added the css:

> THEME_LOCATION\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

And at last but not least I added this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript">require(['bootstrap']);</script>
```

to

> THEME_LOCATION\Magento_Theme\templates\html\header.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header $block
 */
$welcomeMessage = $block->getWelcome();
?>



<?php switch ($block->getShowPart()):
    case 'welcome': ?>
        <li class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
            <!-- ko if: customer().fullname  -->
            <span class="logged-in" data-bind="text: new String('<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Welcome, %1!', '%1')) ?>').replace('%1', customer().fullname)">
            </span>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: customer().fullname  -->
            <span class="not-logged-in" data-bind='html:"<?= $block->escapeHtml($welcomeMessage) ?>"'></span>
            <?= $block->getBlockHtml('header.additional') ?>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </li>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                    "components": {
                        "customer": {
                            "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">require(['bootstrap']);</script>

    <?php break; ?>

    <?php case 'other': ?>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
    <?php break; ?>

<?php endswitch; ?>
```

At the end I executed `php bin/magento cache:flush` to clear the cache.

But I get `require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: bootstrap` if I load a site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was thrown, because magento was unable to load the script, because it is expected to be in `THEME_LOCATION\Magento_Theme\web\js` instead of `THEME_LOCATION\web\js`

Another error source was because I had to use `bootstrap.bundle.js` instead of `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` !

Also don't forget to change the path:

> THEME_LOCATION\Magento_Theme\requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'bootstrap':'Magento_Theme/js/bootstrap.bundle'
    },
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```